# Display/print colours from annotated data frame

Tags: r, colors, dataframe

I am looking for a way to print a data frame that has colour values assigned to categories, as something like a legend.

```
> color.df
  name   color
1    a #E41A1C
2    b #AA3B50
3    c #705C83
```

The output I want would be a rendered table that has two columns, one with the name, and one coloured in the respective colour code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `legend` function, although it's no really a table. Below an example with a blank plot:

```
color.df = read.table(text="name  color
  a     '#E41A1C'
  b     '#AA3B50'
  c     '#705C83'", header=T)

#blank plot
plot(1, type="n", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")

legend("center", fill=color.df$color, legend=color.df$name, cex=5)
```

[image]